# Open MS Office file with AppleScript

Tags: sharepoint, applescript

I have a vbscript file that will open a document with the correct program using SharePoint.OpenDocuments, which is present if Microsoft Office is installed. It's basically: `CreateObject("SharePoint.OpenDocuments.2").EditDocument("MyDocument.docx")` where MyDocument.docx can be anything and the correct program will open.

Is there a way of achieving the same thing in AppleScript on a Mac if Microsoft Office is installed (or even otherwise)?

Thanks,

Adam.

UPDATE: The location of the file will be something like "http://myserver/myfile.doc" and this will be hard coded into the script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
set chosenFile to choose file
tell application "Finder"
    open chosenFile
end tell
```

The `open` command can be further expanded to accept a reference to an application and other arguments related to opening the file, but the above is all you really need if you don't need to specify the application.

Comment: I think I left out an important stipulation - the location of the file will be something like "http:///myserver/myfile.doc" and this will be hard coded in the script. I can't get the above to work like that but thanks.

Comment: That's a tough one. I'm fairly sure Mac OS X will require you to download the file before opening it. There is the "URL Access Scripting" library, but that's just a front-end for `curl`, and all that does is download/upload files. You may need to find a Cocoa-based solution here.

Comment: Well thanks for you help, will look into Cocoa and accept this as the answer.